# Convert factor to date class for multiple columns

Tags: r

I have 7 columns in my dataset. I want to convert 4 variables (2 to 5 column) from factor to date format. I can do it one column at a time, but I want to know if there is a shortcut through which I can convert all of them together.

Currently this is how I do it.

```
SampleData$column2<-as.Date(SampleData$column2,format="%Y/%m%/%d")
SampleData$column3<-as.Date(SampleData$column3,format="%Y/%m%/%d")
SampleData$column4<-as.Date(SampleData$column4,format="%Y/%m%/%d")
SampleData$column5<-as.Date(SampleData$column5,format="%Y/%m%/%d")
```

Comment: I'd go with `SampleData[, 2:5] <- as.Date(sapply(SampleData[, 2:5], as.Date, format="%Y/%m%/%d"), origin="1970-01-01")`. `as.Date()` wrapper, because `sapply` would output numerics otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the format of your dates, you may try this:

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(a = 1:2,
                 d1 = factor(c("2013/01/01", "2014/01/01")),
                 d2 = factor(c("2013/01/01", "2014/01/01")),
                 b = 3:4)

df[ , 2:3] <- lapply(df[ , 2:3], as.Date)

str(df)
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ a : int  1 2
# $ d1: Date, format: "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01"
# $ d2: Date, format: "2013-01-01" "2014-01-01"
# $ b : int  3 4
```

Comment: This is what is used                                            SampleData[,2:5]<-lapply(SampleData[,2:5],as.Date,origin="1970-01-01")   lapply(SampleData[,2:5],class)                                          This seems to be working. Thanks